# How to make auto-generated unique id fields readonly in protobuf?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, rpc

I am very new to protobuf so please bare with me.

I noticed that it is common to have a unique identifier in a protobuf message type like so:

```
message ToDo {
    int64 id = 1; // unique id
    string title = 2;
    string description = 3;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp reminder = 4;
}
```

The message type can then be used in a service for a create request e.g.

```
service ToDoService {
  rpc Create(Todo) returns (CreateResponse) {}
}
```

My expected behaviour is the request to be processed with the `id` generated when inserting into the DB. However, this means that an `id` can still be passed in the request payload, but will essentially be ignored, since the `id` field in `ToDo` is only relevant for read responses.

For example, `todo.Id` is not referenced at all in the `Create` method below.

```
func (s *toDoServiceServer) Create(ctx context.Context, todo *v1.ToDo) (*v1.CreateResponse, error) {
    
    // ... not relevant

    // insert ToDo entity data
    res, err := c.ExecContext(ctx, "INSERT INTO ToDo(`Title`, `Description`, `Reminder`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
        todo.ToDo.Title, todo.ToDo.Description, reminder)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Error(codes.Unknown, "failed to insert into ToDo-> "+err.Error())
    }

    // get ID of creates ToDo
    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Error(codes.Unknown, "failed to retrieve id for created ToDo-> "+err.Error())
    }

    return &v1.CreateResponse{
        Id:  id,
    }, nil
}
```

In my opinion this is a bit confusing when making a request to the service, since it could be assumed that an `id` should be supplied, but in reality it should not be. Since there are no readonly fields in protobuf, is the only option to have two different message types for `ToDo`, where `id` is only present in one? e.g.

```
message ToDoRequest {
    // no id
    string title = 1;
    string description = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp reminder = 3;
}

message ToDo {
    int64 id = 1; // unique id
    string title = 2;
    string description = 3;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp reminder = 4;
}
```

That way `ToDoRequest` is only used for create/update requests and `ToDo` is only used for read responses. My only problem is that it seems tedious defining all other fields twice just to make `id` 'readonly'.

Answer (score 2):

You can compose messages too

```
syntax = "proto3";

package todo;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message ToDo {
    string title = 1;
    string description = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp reminder = 3;
}

message ToDoEntity {
    int64 id = 1;
    ToDo todo = 2;
}

message ToDoRequest {
    ToDo todo = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of this approach but wasn't too fond on it given that id is at a higher level in the hierarchy than the rest of the fields. Maybe I'm being too picky though...